# How to delete the first subset of each set of column in a data file?

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have a data file with more than 40000 column. In header each column's name begins with C1 , c2, ..., cn and each set of c has one or several subset for example c1. has 2 subsets. I need to delete first column(subset) of each set of c. for example if input looks like :

input:

```
    c1.20022  c1.31012  c2.44444  c2.87634  c2.22233 c3.00444  c3.44444 
     1    1         0         1         0         0         0         1     
     2    0         1         0         0         1         0         1     
     3    0         1         0         0         1         1         0     
     4    1         0         1         0         0         1         0     
     5    1         0         1         0         0         1         0     
     6    1         0         1         0         0         1         0
```

I need the output be like:

```
    c1.31012  c2.87634  c2.22233  c3.44444 
     1    0         0         0         1     
     2    1         0         1         1     
     3    1         0         1         0     
     4    0         0         0         0     
     5    0         0         0         0     
     6    0         0         0         0     
     7    1         0         0         0
```

Any suggestion please?

update: If there be no space between digits in row (which is th real situation of my data set) then what should I do? my mean is that my real data looks like this:
input:

```
c1.20022  c1.31012  c2.44444  c2.87634  c2.22233 c3.00444  c3.44444 
         1    1010001     
         2    0100101     
         3    0100110     
         4    1010010     
         5    1010010     
         6    1010010
```

and output:

```
c1.31012  c2.87634  c2.22233  c3.44444 
         1    0001     
         2    1011     
         3    1010     
         4    0000     
         5    0000     
         6    0000     
         7    1000
```

Comment: Loop through the first row, record the column number for the first header of each subset in a list (or as the key in a hash). Then loop through all rows, and loop through all columns, and skip any column that's in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution: It first reads the header line, uses a regex to extract the column name before a dot, and keeps a list of column numbers to keep. It then uses the indices to print only the wanted columns from the header and remaining lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @header = split ' ', <>;
my $last = q();
my @keep;
for my $i (0 .. $#header) {
    my ($prefix) = $header[$i] =~ /(.*)\./;
    if ($prefix eq $last) {
        push @keep, $i + 1;
    }
    $last = $prefix;
}
unshift @header, q();
say join "\t", @header[@keep];

while (<>) {
    my @columns = split;
    say join "\t", @columns[@keep];
}
```

Update:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @header = split ' ', <>;
my $last = q();
my @keep;
for my $i (0 .. $#header) {
    my ($prefix) = $header[$i] =~ /(.*)\./;
    if ($prefix eq $last) {
        push @keep, $i;
    }
    $last = $prefix;
}
say join "\t", @header[@keep];

while (<>) {
    my ($line_number, $all_digits) = split;
    my @digits = split //, $all_digits;
    say join "\t", $line_number, join q(), @digits[@keep];
}
```

Comment: thank you. if there be no tab between digitd in rows,then How should I change the program for that? in fact in my real data except header, in subsequest row all digits are beside each other like: first row: 0001. so in this case wich part of the program should be changed?

Comment: @zara: You'll have to remove the line number, then split on `//` and don't join on `"\t"`, but use `""` or `q()`.

Comment: when I run the first script in my real data, I get this error:Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./first.perl line 21, <> line 3986. Can you guide me how I can get ride out of this error? my data has 3986 rows. could this be a problem?

Comment: The last line has fewer columns or it's empty.